# One laptop unable to boot for second partition of USB flash drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I have a USB memory stick with two partitions:

```
sdb                                                                     
├─sdb1 ntfs                        2D2208E03A1506BD                     
└─sdb2 iso9660 Kubuntu 17.10 amd64 2018-01-05-21-27-02-00
```

sdb1 is a general data storage NTFS partition, and sdb2 contains the Kubutnu 17.10.1 installer (which was created using `dd if=kubuntu17.10.iso of=/dev/sdb2`).

This works as expected on my ThinkPad T470p - as in I can boot from sdb2 and install Kubuntu 17.10. However, on another laptop of mine (a Defiance II), it only gives me the option to boot from "partition 1".

Is there anything I can do to make my Defiance II boot from partition 2, or is this just a "hard-wired" limitation of the laptop?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a UEFI / BIOS thing, Try installing to USB using mkusb or the latest UNetbootin. Both should work with either UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: I'll compare the BIOS settings of both laptops when I get home - make sure they both have UEFI enabled.